# Storing room data on Socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am making a web app with Socket.io and I want to store data for each of the rooms. The data includes some data about users, as well as the room itself, etc., all in a JavaScript object.

Now my question is if I simply have an array `let rooms = []` on my `server.js` which I manipulate and use to store data, would that be OK?

If I deploy to production and have users on the site, would this be fine and work as expected? I am not sure if I need to implement a DB here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to get out of it. Using local state (i.e. what you are doing with `let rooms = []`) will work just fine (I've done this and had success with it).

The downside is that your state will be in one server's memory. So if that server goes down or you restart it, you will lose all that state (all your rooms). Also, if you need to scale beyond one server then this won't work because each server would have a different list of room data. Your clients would get a different view of things depending on which server they connect to.

The reason this approach has worked for me previously was because my data was very transient and I could accept losing it. I also did not have scaling needs.

In summary, if your situation is such that:

1. you won't have more users than you can handle on one server instance at any given time
2. it's okay if your data gets reset

Then go ahead with this - it worked great for me! Otherwise, if you want to make sure your room data doesn't get reset or if you need more than one server, you will want something like a database.